# Creating Window Service of TCP/IP server - Chat Application

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, tcp, tcplistener

I have a client and a server that communicates in a network using TCP/IP protocol. Whenever I start the application in Visual Studio. I have a button **StartListening** that starts the server and listen the client requests.

Now I'm trying to create that `StartListening` button into a Window Service and don't need to click on the button for listening.

Here is a server code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(StartListening);
}

public void StartListening()
{
    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    int nPort = 8001;
    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress,nPort);
    tcpListener.Start();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[256];

    while (true)
    {
        Socket socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();

        int res = socket.Receive(bytes);
        ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string str = asen.GetString(bytes);
        //logic

        socket.Close();
    }
}
```

**Note:** In `//logic` in above code what thing I should place to communicate server with clients?

Comment: You forgot to start the thread by the way

Comment: that's obvious to service starts. edit

Comment: Well no, it isn't.   Asking for what code to insert to communicate with client is kinda redundant if it never gets there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think two threads not working because while True is thread and Actually two threads not work in the same time here is code may be fix your problem

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(//Your method name here));
thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

To reply to your client: `socket.Send(asen.GetBytes("reply"));`